# Solve an equation with two functions

Tags: problem-solving, inverse-function

I have got the equation

$$y = F(x)-x*G(x)$$

and want to solve it for $x$.
So i am searching for something like:

$$x = F^{-1}(y)-yG^{-1}(y)$$

(which is wrong obviously)

In my context $F(x)$ is the probability density function and $G(x)$ is the survival function of a normal distribution. Therefore $F^{-1}(x)$ should be the cumulative distribution function and $G^{-1}(x)$ should be the inverse survival function.

Comment: You are searching for "something like" Newton Raphson.

Comment: What is $x(x)$? it seems like you have used the same letter for the function name and the input variable...

Comment: @Vedant Chourey where did OP's $G(x)$ go in the firs equation? Please refrain from making it worse. Better to ask OP to use mathJax so that they are going to learn it.

Comment: Sorry. This should be x*G(x)

Comment: @KurtG.. Depending on the ranges, it *could* be possible to have an *approximate* inverse even if this be an infinite summation.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici $F(x)$ and $(G(x)$ are the probability density function and survival function of a normal distribution. I have to work with means (mu) of few hundreds to coulpe of hundred thousands with CVs (coeficcient of variation) between 0.1 and 1.5

Comment: It is possible to have an approximation of the form $x=H(y)$. By the way, welcome to the site !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yes, this is what i mean with the inverse functions. Let´s say $F(x) = z$, then $x = F^-1(z)$. Therefore i can say for my original equation: $ x = F^-1(y+x*G(x)$ and $x = G^-1((F(x)-y)/x)$, but both equations have $x$ on both sides and so this does not quite solve my problem.

Comment: I said $x=H(y)$ and not $x = F^{-1}(y)-yG^{-1}(y)$. There is a major difference. Moreover, show what you tried and explain where you are stuck (otherwise, the question could be closed soon).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145422/discussion-between-claude-leibovici-and-lebron10).

Comment: I have been waiting for you in the chat room. What a pity since I had in hands a good approximation for the case of $\mu=0$ and $\sigma\neq 1$.